# Post Method 405 Error

Tags: python, flask

I have a decently intermediate understanding of APIs, and am not trying to host information I've got from APIs onto the web.

This incredibly simple code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/temperature', methods=['POST'])
def temperature():
    zipcode = request.form['zip']
    r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=' +zipcode+',us&appid=9b56b06ab4c7f06821ccf55e3e10fce5')
    json_obj = r.text
    return json_obj

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hi'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Is not giving me anything (except the 405 error).

Can someone please explain why my POST method is not working?

Comment: What exactly do you do to get 405? How do you test this?

Comment: Hey! I go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/temperature

Comment: When you browse to a page, it uses `GET`. You need to write test code to use `POST`. For example `requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/temperature', {'zip': '12345'})`

Comment: Thanks for your update on the question, but you seem to have only included the first few lines of the server output. Please show us the log when you actually request the `/temperature` page.

Comment: It was very, very confusing to read your question after you had essentially changed its nature.  The 405 would occur with the code you currently have and it *wouldn't* with your new code.  If you have a different question, please ask a different question; however, I strongly encourage you to work through the main issue you're having after you've successfully resolved this part.

Comment: When I have "@app.route('/temperature', methods=['POST'])"

I get error 405 - method not allowed.

when I have "@app.route('/temperature', methods=['GET','POST'])"

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not entirely sure what you have done, here's what I think you did:

You accessed the `/temperature` page in your browser which is by default a `GET`-Request.

You then get returned a [405 Method Not Allowed Error](https://httpstatusdogs.com/405-method-not-allowed), because your route explicitly requires that the page will be accessed via the HTTP-`POST` Method.

Modify `@app.route('/temperature', methods=['POST'])` to `@app.route('/temperature', methods=['POST', 'GET'])` and you should be fine.

Comment: Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: You get that error after you changed the line and reloaded the page? Please make sure your server reloaded the code as well.

Comment: yes, I do get this error when I change the code and reload the page. I even run it as python script_name.py

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show me what you have changed? Please include the relevant lines from your servers' log as well. This change should work in principle, maybe the call to the external API returns the error, which is passed on by flask...

Comment: @Maurice:  Please don't suggest that the OP wantonly change their question in this fashion, as it genuinely invalidates your answer.

Comment: @Makoto I get your point. What would be a better way to ask him to add new information?

Comment: They need to ask a new question.  But in all honesty, asking a question for every problem on Stack Overflow isn't the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my answer from /r/ flask here, just for posterity.

the line in your code: `zipcode = request.form['zip']` implies that you are submitting data from an HTML form to the view via a POST.

If there is no form, then `request.form['zip']` does nothing, and is most likely raising the error. Considering that I see no route in your logic there that points to any HTML, I'm guessing that's the issue.

If you have not built a form for the user to submit the zip code, then you could build it into the route logic. For example, you could do:

```
@app.route('/temperature/<zipcode>')
def temperature(zipcode):
    # add some kind of validation here to make sure it's a valid zipcode
    r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=' +zipcode+',us&appid=DONT_SHARE_YOUR_API_KEY')
    json_obj = r.text
    return json_obj
```

You could then use `http://127.0.0.1:5000/temperature/20003` to see the data for that zip code.

(as a side note, it's often unwise to publicly share your API keys. you may want to generate a new key.)